# Update Inner Join Table with new rows

Tags: php, mysql, magento, join

I created an Inner Join Table using 3 different tables, now what I want to do is to change that new table with products when I insert, delete or edit.
My idea was to use a temporary inner join table with the same parameters and comparing the two, inserting new rows if they did not exist before, deleting them if I eliminate products and updating the existing ones if I change their values.
Is there any way I can do this? I don't know if I should use JOIN, UPDATE, INSERT or a combination.

The script I used to create the table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE marketplace_overlay_data_updater AS 
  SELECT 
    marketplace_userdata.partnerstatus, 
    marketplace_userdata.mageuserid, 
    marketplace_product.mageproductid, 
    marketplace_product.userid, 
    catalog_product_entity.entity_id, 
    catalog_product_entity.categoria 
    FROM marketplace_product INNER JOIN marketplace_userdata 
    ON marketplace_userdata.mageuserid = marketplace_product.userid
    INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity 
    ON catalog_product_entity.entity_id = marketplace_product.mageproductid
    ORDER BY marketplace_userdata.mageuserid
```

The target table is called **marketplace_overlay_data** with the same structure.

Comment: just fiddle the question. `http://sqlfiddle.com/`